# Java/Groovy: Non Deterministic Crypto Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, groovy, non-deterministic

I'm working on a Groovy application that has to provide users with a link containing encrypted query parameters.  Currently we use the AES encryption algorithm with the same IV used for all links.  We know this is bad (hence the reason we want to switch), but the reason this was done was to limit the size of the query parameters (including a base64 encoded 16 byte initialization vector with each query parameter makes the links very long).  We'd like to switch to a non deterministic algorithm so that we have the required randomness in the query data but don't have to store the IV in the query parameters.

Since we're working with Groovy we can use anything from Java.  Having not done much encryption work though I'm not sure which algorithm to start looking into.  Ideally we'd want one that's available in Java SE or as a freely usable Java library.  Also any links with details on how to implement these algorithms is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your security requirement for the query? Do want it to confidential - that means that no external party is allowed to find out its content - or do you want it to be authentic - that means no user can manipulate a query you have created (or both)? As a measure to avoid the cryptography altogether: Can you provide a link with a random query id instead of the query itself and look up the query from your database?

Answer (score 0):

The aim is to not use the same initialization vector twice. If you have something unique in the request that the server know when decrypting, you might use that as the initialization vector.

Otherwise, you could simply use a counter as the initialization vector. Keep a central counter that you increase each time you encrypt something, and put that counter in front of the encrypted data. Then expand this counter to a 16 byte initialization vector.